# MySQL joins and COUNT(*) or MAX() from another table

Tags: mysql, syntax

I have the following syntax returning the expected results:

```
SELECT 
material.period AS "Period", 
material.style AS "Style", 
material.artist AS "Artist", 
material.title AS "Title", 
material.path AS "Path", 
path.step AS "Steps" 
FROM material 
INNER JOIN path ON material.path=path.material;
```

path.step is returning multiple rows, as expected. Both material.path and path.material are integer fields, as is path.step.

What I would like is to get the maximum value of path.step to reduce the number of rows returned. The path.step field is ordinal, so I am considering count function.

This syntax returns the expected results.

```
SELECT COUNT(path.step) AS "Steps" FROM path GROUP BY material;
```

It seems best to use MAX() instead of COUNT(). I realize I need to filter the first result set to get the second result set as the desired outcome. I am not sure if a sub-query in the WHERE clause is best or if a CASE is best.

What are your recommendations, please?

Thanks,
SHD

***UPDATE TO POST, RESOLVED***

Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

I reviewed the proposed syntax and reviewed the provided URLs. Notably, the fine manual.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

I settled on this syntax below. It works as expected.

```
SELECT 
material.period AS "Period", 
material.style AS "Style", 
material.artist AS "Artist", 
material.title AS "Title", 
material.path AS "Path", 
path.step AS "Steps" 

FROM material 
INNER JOIN path ON material.path=path.material 

WHERE  path.step=(SELECT MAX(path.step)
              FROM path
              WHERE material.path = path.material)

ORDER BY material.period ASC, material.style ASC, material.artist ASC, material.title ASC, material.path ASC, Steps ASC;
```

Kindest Regards,
SHD

Comment: Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  material   AS m
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    material, MAX(step) AS step
  FROM
    path
  GROUP BY
    material
)
  AS p
    ON p.material = m.path
WHERE
  m.material IN (3,5,7)
```

The sub query (inline view) is ONLY evaluated for the relevant materials in the outer query.

Just make sure you have the appropriate indexes on each table. `(material, step)` as a composite index on the path table, for example.

As a side note, having `p.material = m.path` appears very odd, are you sure that's the foreign key relationship? If so, the column in the path table seems badly named.